# How to fix these jagged lines?

Tags: javascript, css, antialiasing

I want to know is there a way around to fix these jagged lines (edges of a `div`). I used CSS `perspective` and `rotate` to give my tiles block (shown in the image below) a 3d click effect just as happens in Windows 8 Start Menu Tiles.

[image]

Rotating the `divs` `onclick` causes these jagged lines to appear which is very bad to me and my tiles. Is there a way around this to minimize these jagged lines by any means, CSS, JS, anything?

**UPDATE:**
I am providing a JSFiddle demo below to help you get an idea on exactly how I created my tiles and gave them a 3d look.
http://jsfiddle.net/1hz5hk5s/

*This problem is with Firefox only.*

Comment: Could you create a quick demo using JSFiddle (or something else)?

Comment: I've created and added it.

Comment: it looks good on my screen. Im on toshiba chromebook 2, chrome version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)

Comment: I can only reproduce this in Firefox. IE and Chrome look good.

Comment: I just checked it on my Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m, and in IE, the jagged lines were very minimal, almost smooth. But in my Firefox 34, they look like as I have provided screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website (http://demosthenes.info/blog/689/More-Tricks-and-Tips-For-CSS-3D-Smoothing-Transforms-amp-Fixing-Floated-Elements) seems to offer a relevant solution of adding a border of 1px.
So the relevant CSS would be:

```
img:focus{transform: rotateY(12deg); outline: 1px solid transparent;}
```

This should make the image rotate 12 degrees on the y-axis on click. However, browser prefixes should be added just to make sure that it is cross compatible as each browser handles the rotations differently.

Comment: my tiles are not `img`, actually they are created totally using html, css and js. check out the JSFiddle demo I'm just going to add. And I didn't check that link, after adding the demo I'm gonna check it.

Comment: Okay, the idea should be about the same though. Reading the comments makes me think that it is a browser specific problem. Try it out and see if it works.

Comment: can i use outline on `div` if it already have a `border`? I'm currently editing the fiddle, adding the `outline` but I am not able to see any changes.

Comment: it cannot be resolved, the problem is with Firefox only, Can you check on latest version of Firefox? I just checked your link and I saw that the smoothing applied image also appear jagged in Firefox but in IE it appears smooth.

Comment: Yes. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp . Are you trying it with the browser prefixes? It seems to be isolated to Firefox.

Comment: no i didn't add browser prefix. should i do `-moz-outline: 1px solid transparent` ?

Comment: I checked both, without vendor prefix and with vendor prefix, but it is still not working in mozilla. the link you provided in your answer was also not able to smooth the image in Firefox, although the image was smooth in IE. Its the problem with FF only.

Comment: Did you try the browser prefixes on the transforms as well?

Comment: I think it cannot be fixed in FF, I tried vendor prefixing all properties but that also didn't work. And the `outline` property works without vendor prefix in my FF, I just confirmed it with this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1hz5hk5s/1/  Do you have Firefox? Check it in Firefox please.

Comment: Hey!!, thank you so much for your help. The `outline` method worked well, there was something problem with the version of FF I was using, I updated my FF and then tried this, after that the edges were smooth as they appeared in IE or Chrome. It works!! http://jsfiddle.net/1hz5hk5s/3/